# What is best approach / methodology to manage hierarchical object state in MVVM based app?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I work on GUI and deal with complex objects  that is objects have other objects and those object might have other objects.

These objects are manipulated (often almost at the same time) by various views, view models, services, nhibernate, and you name it -  doing in simple things like, save/update/delete/validate and etc.

In most cases things like  NotifyPropertyChanged is enough, but not always. Sometimes i resolve to calling EventAggregator BUT when **object graph is big**  and especially collection of such objects - it gets so messy i keep loosing ends  and not sure what is exact state of a particular object and often not sure if that is still same object or some loose copy of it;

So my question is what is best approach / methodology to **manage object states** and avoid "state explosion"?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. Actually for our, not so small, application, we do it exactly like that. We have our own derived framework for MVVM; we have viewmodels that are for one specific purpose; sometimes we have a base viewmodel for all "states" and derive from this for specific states; We toggle sometimes views with trigger; For large amount of data, we use ui virtualization and sometimes lazy loading. Its all very local, so i think there is no one-perfect solution.

Comment: thanks dowhilefor. I extended prism and yes i go triggers, visual states for ui , unit test, but can't shake the feeling that something is not right. I guess maybe what I am looking for a pattern or approach in general is how properly to validate object state before manipulating it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to take note of a book [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857258) by `Robert C. Martin` and `Micah Martin`, there are many good examples where it is shown how to design a system by `UML`, and other similar methods. Specifically, it is shown why you should refactor your code, that can be stored in abstract classes and what is not. You can immediately see an example with a coffee maker `Mark IV`, where he developed a truly independent interface.

According to my feelings, the main principle of MVVM - is the independence of the data from its representations. I like trying to make separate modules, which implement separate logic, not knowing about the data. For example, SQL module, SMTP module, etc, which simply contain some methods like `ConnectToDb()` or `SendEmail()`, the main logic is in `ViewModel`, she combines these Work-modules with the data model.

Useful to draw a diagram before designing the system, but do not get involved too. The main thing is to see the main parts in the paper, and that the others would understand it as well as *you* know (or architect).

Comment: I wasn't sure if by your frase "she combines these Work-modules with the data model." you referring to me, but the answer to your question , nope I don't do that. State diagrams sound like a good idea. I have this book will look at it too. Thanks

Comment: Ok,this book it only briefly covers Finite State Machine versus Hierarchical State Machine.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify by introducing additional structure. The best methodology is giving the application more structure. Divide the application into smaller parts internal living of which you can oversee and control well. Let these parts be hidden behind facade/adapter types which expose only a simplified view on that part of the system. Repeat recursively as long as necessary. Use formal models to define structure and inter-communication rules, e.g. UML 2.0 hierarchical state machines usually fit well... I know, this is just a generic engineering bla-bla, but it could help...

Comment: I realize this topic can go on forever in terms of bla bla bla, but thanks for great answer and the pointer . Its more clear now where to look;

Comment: I found something called "Ultimate Hook" pattern from the 80's ...  nice . Thanks!

Comment: @Inga  I have done some digging into origins of the "Ultimate Hook".  [Here are my findings.](http://reconvolution.blogspot.com/2015/07/the-original-ultimate-hook.html)  The way I see it, the 80's-90's *ultimate hook* is a callback which accepts messages (command pattern).  Since one can call such callback with all kinds of messages, the program doesn't necessarily need other hooks.  Maybe that's why it was dubbed "ultimate".